Car ran for 2 miles with an oil tank leak, is the engine done?
I ran over a metal cube like shape and made some nasty holes in my oil pan, soon as it happend oil fell in the mufflers and caused a gas like smell according to a mechanic. I ran the car for about 2 miles and ran fine after the 1st mile it lost power and eventually stopped accelerating, do yall think my engine is done for?

Did the oil pressure light illuminate while you were driving?

Yes, soon as i hit the object it came on.

Why did you keep driving with the oil pressure light on?

i didnt know how serious driving with no oil was, its my first car and it was around 6 am and close to my house in my head it was better to get there and check the problem out. The oil pan is going to get fixed and ill find out if the engine is good or not this week but i cant get the car off my mind and just been thinking about it and its been making me anxious so im just trying to get hope that the engine is good. It only has 51k miles and has been taken good care off

There is a possibility that not too much damage has been caused and that the engine starts and runs OK.  If the oil pressure light ever illuminates, stop the engine as soon as possible.  Even if the dipstick shows plenty of oil, the oil pump could have broken giving no oil pressure, which will cause damage.

thats what i been praying to god for hopefully the engine is still okay, thanks for the advice and for taking ur time to respond tho really appreciate it have a good day !

Chances are that it is. You dumped enough oil to cause a low oil pressure condition (of which you were warned) and still ran the engine. Good chance of bearings spun, which will require quite a bit of parts and labor to repair. Could've avoided all that if you shut down the engine immediately after the impact.

Thanks for letting me know. will i be able to fix the engine or am i going to have to replace it ?

It may be fixable, but a lot of work either way. Depending on the overall value of the car it may not be worth it. Another option is to source a used engine and put that in instead.

yea i was thinking that it would take a while tho its a 2014 mustang and engines are going for 6k with more than 70k miles
